# WCF-NetNamedPipe's ChannelFactory

Tags: wcf, netnamedpipebinding

**Update 20121214**
consultation with the developers of the conflict service, 
they use **net.pipe://echonet** as service address,
and use **DuplexChannelFactory**.
why it will block my Pipe?

---

**Question:**

I have a very simple WCF application.
Service and Client through NetNamedPipe communication. 
But it is strange , some machines may be the reason because other software, 
resulting in the ChannelFactory began to call the Service, throw an exception : System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException .

How could I know which application catch my WCF message, 
and how should I avoid this problem.

here is exception:

```
System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: The requested upgrade is not supported by 'net.pipe://localhost/xxxx/xxxx'. This could be due to mismatched bindings (for example security enabled on the client and not on the server)

Server stack trace: 
  System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionUpgradeHelper.DecodeFramingFault(ClientFramingDecoder decoder, IConnection connection, Uri via, String contentType, TimeoutHelper& timeoutHelper)
  System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.SendPreamble(IConnection connection, ArraySegment`1 preamble, TimeoutHelper& timeoutHelper)
  System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.DuplexConnectionPoolHelper.AcceptPooledConnection(IConnection connection, TimeoutHelper& timeoutHelper)
  System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionPoolHelper.EstablishConnection(TimeSpan timeout)
  System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
  System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
  System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
  System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
  System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOpenOnce.System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ICallOnce.Call(ServiceChannel channel, TimeSpan timeout)
  System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOnceManager.CallOnce(TimeSpan timeout, CallOnceManager cascade)
  System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
  System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
  System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
  System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
  System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
  xxx.xxxxx.Communication.Contracts.IxxxComClientService.Register(ClientInfo clientInfo)
  xxx.xxxxx.Communication.xxxComClient.ActionClientRegisterOnlineClientInfo(IxxxComClientService channel)
  xxx.xxxxx.Communication.xxxComClient.ActionReceivedClientOnline(EndpointAddress endpoint)
```

here is my code'

----------------------------Service------------------------------

```
 using (var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(StringReverser), new[] { new Uri("net.pipe://localhost") }))
 {
     host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IStringReverser), new NetNamedPipeBinding(), "PipeReverse");
     host.Open();

     Console.WriteLine("Service is available. Press <ENTER> to exit.");
     Console.ReadLine();

     host.Close();
  }
```

--------------------------Client---------------------------------

```
var pipeFactory = new ChannelFactory<IStringReverser>(new NetNamedPipeBinding(), new EndpointAddress("net.pipe://localhost/PipeReverse"));
Console.WriteLine("pipeFactory Created. Press <Exit> to exit");
var pipeProxy = pipeFactory.CreateChannel();
Console.WriteLine("pipeProxy Created.");

while (true)
{
   var str = Console.ReadLine();
   Console.WriteLine("pipe: " + pipeProxy.ReverseString(str));
}
```

Comment: ok,i update my question.

Comment: If you say it works on some machines but not in others, then it's possible that the machines which don't may not support the security model which the default `NetNamedPipeBinding` uses (based on the error message). Try creating the binding with `new NetNamedPipeBinding(NetNamedPipeSecurityMode.None)` to see if this problem goes away.

Comment: Yes , I tried , but failed .
Later, I discovered one of the reasons is because there is a service , when this service is running NetNamedPipe will be blocked. Just stop the service , run very good.

i want to find out ,why the service is block my netnamedpipe. and i try the wcf trace.but i could not get reason.pleas help me.thank you .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- b1. the service, is host on windowsservice,run as administrator
- b2. the service, is set net.pipe://echonet as his address
- b3. my service,  is self host,run as localuser

windowsservice > localuser
so, namedpipe will redirect to the service.

- s1. stop the service
- s2. change my service host, let it host on
  windowsservice.